# HowTo: Bootloader Jump-Mark

Tags: bootloader

I am currently thinkering on bootloaders for embedded applications.

**In particular, i am stuck on how to provide a reliable "Jump Mark".**

What i mean with Jump-Mark:
The basic bootloader-design i am thinking of is as follows:
Bootloader resides @flash_start -> Is fetched after MCU reset.
To provide a "clean" (e.g. all peripherials cleared etc.) state to the user-app, the bootloader
triggers an MCU-Reset (Watchdog, Software-Reset, etc.) before jumping to the application.

To not get stuck in an endless loop (POR->BL starts->Timeout->Request to Jump so WDT-Reset->BL starts) some kind of mark must be provided to signal to the bootloader code, to execute the actual jump-to-application before going into "listen for Host and wait for timeout" mode which is to be executed only after POR.

**Currently i have three solutions in mind:**

1. Use the internal MCU registers and determine the reset-source. If !POR then do the Jump, if POR run "normal" code -> Requires dedicated registers (Not all MCUs have them)
2. Use a Mark (Struct with some data, CRC secured) in flash/eeprom/ram -> Can contain more information then only jump yes/no, but requires flash/eeprom or RAM which only clears on POR - also some fiddeling with linker required.
3. Use external RC-Tank on a GPIO. Set GPIO low after POR (RC-time constant high so EMV is not a problem) and goto "listen" mode. If timeout: Set GPIO high, wait for 5 time-constants. Do Reset. Check if GPIO high. If so, set low an jump -> Requires dedicated GPIO. Also: Is it EMV-stable?

I personally would go with Opt. 2:
Provide a special section with the linker outside of .data and .bss in RAM. Write the "Check Jmp-RAM" function in a way, that no globals are required. Run it before startupcode. If Mark is present (CRC and so on) jump to application. If not run "listen" mode.

**Why would i do it?**

As the "Jump-Mark" is an essential part of the code, it should not rely on specific MCU ressources -> So no HAL to determine reset-source - requires only Reset-persistent (not POR persistent) RAM which can be used by the application after the bootloader did the jump.
It does on the other hand not require a EEPROM or a dedicated flash-space.
Also, no external parts are required.

**So my question is: How is this done in a proper FW?**

Comment: Are you after a generic solution? May be impossible. Do you know what parts of the whole MCU is reset with hardware reset, and are all your MCUs alike? For example on IBM PC there is a reserved memory word which set to special values boot in a special way, e.g. ctrl-alt-del makes a warm boot without re-checking the memory. IBM AT used a battery backed RTC/SRAM chip to store a byte for what to do after reset.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am after a some-what hardware independent (Not fixed on ARM) bootloader to be used on MCUs. BUT: I want to keep the HAL-Interface as small as possible, as the Bootloader is to be used on a wast variety of different controller families (Cores, Peripherials, manufacturers etc.). 

In Essence: The HAL-Layer should only consist of Com_R/W, Flash_R/W and Jump/Reset. I am aware of the fact, that almost all MCUs fullfilling the requirements do provide a Watchdog and a Timer as well. But i dont want to settle on "Has Reset-Source Register" yet

Comment: Just use RAM and then reset it back to 0 before running the main app. You do want to run the bootloader again if the main app crashes, right?

Comment: Yes - correct. The bootloader is to be fetched after every Reset. But it is okay, if the bootloader goes into "listen and wait for timeout" after the app crashes.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent maybe a better term is `flag`, instead of `mark`